# Use the shell method to find the volume of the solid by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis.

Tags: calculus

Use the shell method to find the volume of the solid by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis: $y=x^3, y=8$ and $x=0$.

I need to know if I am rotating around the y-axis using the shell method my definite integral points will be 0 and 8 right? What if I used the disk method?

Please someone hels me as I am a little confused about it.

Comment: What is $x3$???

Comment: oh it is x^3 (x cube )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given region is bounded by the curve $y=x^3$, the horizontal line $y=8$ and the vertical line $x=0$. Using the method of disks, since the solid is obtained by rotating the region about the $y$-axis, the inner radius is 0 and the cross-sectional area is 
$$ A(y) = \pi\left(\sqrt[3]{y}\right)^2 = \pi y^{2/3}. $$
Hence, the volume is
\begin{align*}
V & = \int_0^8 A(y)\, dy \\
& = \pi \int_0^8 y^{2/3}\, dy \\
& = \left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)8^{5/3} \\
& = \frac{96\pi}{5}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: can i ask a question?    why did you put y with the power 3/2 shouldn't it be 2/3

Comment: @yara You are absolutely right. I have edited my answer. Note that I am using the disk method, not the shell method as indicated in your question.

Comment: what if i used the sheel method the radius will be x and the height will be x^3 and the points for the definite integral will be 0 and 8 right ??

Comment: @yara No. If you are using the shell method, then the radius is $x$, the height is $8-x^3$ and the limits of integration are $x=0$ and $x=2$.

Comment: oh right, sorry i got confused . sometimes i have a problem with solving with the shell method when i have to it is kinda complicated

Comment: @yara No worries (:

Comment: thanks anyway :)